# Do people perceive a difference between "phantasy" and "fantasy"?

Tags: differences, connotation, historical-change, homophones

When I started to learn English, I was used to write *phantasy* instead of *fantasy*, and I was always corrected.

I recently noticed that *phantasy* is an English word too.
Do people give to those words a different meaning?

Comment: This is what someone else has to say about this question: http://changingminds.org/disciplines/psychoanalysis/concepts/phantasy_fantasy.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OED notes that  ***fantasy*** and ***phantasy*** are usually considered separate words in modern use:

> In mod. use  *fantasy* and *phantasy*, in spite of their identity in sound and in ultimate etymology, tend to be apprehended as separate words, the predominant sense of the former being ‘caprice, whim, fanciful invention’, while that of the latter is ‘imagination, visionary notion’.

One of its citations is:

> - 1926 G. Coster *Psycho-Analysis* ii. 35 ― The term *phantasy* is much used in analytical psychology, and the fact that its technical meaning differs subtly from its colloquial one leads to some confusion. A phantasy is a day-dream in which desire, unfulfilled in the world of reality, finds an imaginary fulfilment or satisfaction.

Because these were once used interchangeably but are now used differently, you cannot just do an easy ngram or a simple corpus check of one versus the other and make any concrete inference about the results.

The spelling variants throughout the ages are considerable.  The alphas below are the  *f-* forms and the betas the *ph-* forms in this OED citation, and the numbers represent century numbers:

> - *ɑ.* 4-7 fantasi(e, -ye, -azie, -aisie, -aysie, -esi(e, -esy(e, -essy, (5 fantsy, fayntasie, feintasy), 5-6 fantosy, 6-7 fantacie, -y, 4- fantasy.
> - *β.* 6- 8 phantasie, (6 -esie, 6-7 phant’sie, -’sy), 6- phantasy.

Note that our word  ***fancy*** also comes from these, and thus also had both alpha and beta forms:

> - *ɑ.* 5-6 fansey, 6-8 fansie, -ye, 6-7 fancie, -ye, 6- fancy.
> - *β.* 6-8 phansy(e, -cie, -cy, 6-9 phansie.

*Phantasy* is more related to *phantasm* than to  *fancy*.  OED has longer notes about all this.  Here is an excerpt:

> The shortened form **fancy**, which apparently originated in the 15th c., had in the time of Shakspere become more or less differentiated in sense. After the revival of Greek learning, the longer form was often spelt *phantasy*, and its meaning was influenced by the Gr. etymon.

Comment: Does OED have recent examples illustrating the difference?

Answer (score 12):

I have never seen it written **phantasy** much, except in medical texts. The *NOAD* seems to confirm this:

> **phantasy**
>   (noun):
>   variant spelling of **fantasy** (restricted to archaic uses or, in modern use, to the fields of psychology and psychiatry).

Comment: It's also used by fangirls I know.

Comment: @kitukwfyer In what context is the term used?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with F'x about "archaic" uses.

In a literary sense, I'd think of *phantasy* being used by 19th- and early-20th- century writers, such as George Macdonald, Andrew Lang, Lord Dunsany, and Clark Ashton Smith. Even then, *phantasy* was considered an out-of-date usage. When contemporary writers use *phantasy*, they're signalling very strongly that their stories use older times, places, or modes of story-telling.

Answer (score 0):

I think *phantasy* is used in psychoanalysis to indicate unconscious imaginings or ideas, as opposed to *fantasy* referring to conscious imaginings or thoughts.

Comment: Citation needed.

Comment: I'd be interested in a citation.  "Phantasy" seems to be common in translations of Freud.